# permission denied while creating a file object in python

Tags: python, file

i have two python scripts

script1.py1:-

```
def somefunction()
.................
out_file = open("out.txt","w")
#creates a file out.txt and write something into it
out_file.close()
.................
.................


somefunction() #calling somefunction
out_file = open("out.txt","r")
output = open("Final_out.txt","w")
for line in out_file:
    match_for_pattern = re.search(r"^\(.*affected\)$",line)
    if match_for_pattern:
            output.write("")
    else:
            output.write("%s" % line)
out_file.close()
output.close()
```

I wanted to change something in out.txt file, i.e removing some unwanted lines, So i thought to create a new file Final_out.txt with all the changes done in it.

but i'm getting permission denied error when i run the code

ERROR:-

```
output = open("Final_out.txt","w")
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Final_out.txt'
```

I have full permission `chmod 777` in my present working directory,

If i take out the code where i am changing something in my file(out.txt) and place it into a new python script (script2.py) then it is working.

scritp2.py:-

```
out_file = open("out.txt","r")
output = open("Final_out.txt","w")
for line in out_file:
    match_for_pattern = re.search(r"^\(.*affected\)$",line)
    if match_for_pattern:
            output.write("")
    else:
            output.write("%s" % line)
out_file.close()
output.close()
```

script2.py creates a file Final_out.txt in my present directory with all the changes that i want.

how's this possible that my script1.py is not able to do this but script2.py does it without any errors?

Comment: I can see you're working on Linux, what filesystem was you using when the script1 error happened?

Comment: Maybe `out.txt` was open for write by another process?

Comment: i'm using ext3 on Linux x86_64

Comment: @Kos: I'm opening `out.txt` in `somefunction()` but i am closing it as well in the same fucntion after writing on it

Comment: manually create Final_out.txt and open it in append mode see if it works.

Comment: @New_User123 :  did that too, didn't work

Comment: Could you post the result of the command `ls -l` on both of the scripts?

Comment: if your directories are executable, does it infer all the the files wihtin that folder are also executable? check the permissions of the file that does the writing and the file that its written to.